# UICollectionView's prepareLayout and invalidateLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

when reading objc.io's 5th issue on [UICollectionView + UIKit Dynamics](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/collection-views-and-uidynamics.html) , the 2nd section talked about 'Tiling your Dynamic Behaviors for Performance ([related source code](https://github.com/objcio/issue-5-springy-collection-view/blob/master/ASHSpringyCollectionView/ASHSpringyCollectionViewFlowLayout.m))', what confuse me is `prepareLayout` method is continuously called, but `-shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange:` still returns `NO`, and nowhere called `invalidateLayout`. shouldn't it just called once ?

Answer (score 1):

I came across a similar issue myself when testing an iOS7 UICollectionViewFlowLayout on an iOS6 device. On an iOS7 device `prepareLayout` is only called once, but on an iOS6 device it is called when layoutSubviews is trigged by it's parent UIScrollView.

To fix this issue I changed my UICollectionViewFlowLayout class to UICollectionViewLayout. There seems to be a layout issues with UICollectionViewFlowLayout in this case.